# don't use index in pandas-profiling

Tags: pandas-profiling

When running pandas-profiling on a dataframe I see it analyses the index as a variable. Note: My index is a unique key (named UUID)

Is there a way to exclude bringing in the index to report?

I understand I could remove it in pandas but in my head I would like to do

`ProfileReport(df, use_index=False)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that having an option to `use_index=False` in `ProfileReport` would be nice and clean, it apparently doesn't exist (yet).

So currently the only way I can find to exclude bringing the index into the report is by dropping it before profiling:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

This gets the job done.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/859